# Counting voted comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have 3 models

user

```
has_many :comments
has_many :votes
```

comment

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :votes
```

vote

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :comment
```

I want to find if user has any voted comments. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your Vote belongs to User. Does that mean that other users will give a vote directly to a user or does a user only get a vote :through => :comments?

Comment: as I understand, User has_many votes made by him to comments. User can vote comments

Answer (score 1):

```
user.comments.joins(:votes).select("distinct comments.id, comments.*")
```

or you can use scope

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :votes
  scope :with_votes, joins(:votes).select("distinct comments.id, comments.*")
end

#=> user.comments.with_votes
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also add a counter cache to your Comment model for the number of votes it has. Then you could do:

```
user.comments.where("vote_count > 0")
```

Or better yet you could then define a method on the Comment model:

```
def with_votes  
  where("vote_count > 0")  
end
```

And then you could call:

```
user.comments.with_votes
```